# Array elements getting lost between server and browser

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, tomcat, server

I have a Java Tomcat server that sends an array to a browser where it will be displayed in a table.  This was all working perfectly until I added two more elements to the array, and now those two elements never make it to the browser.  I can list out in the log all of the elements before they leave the server and they're all there.  But when I look at the array in the browser after the ajax call, the new elements are missing.   ???

Comment: this is pretty vague. There are infinite reasons why this could happen.. We need more to go on

Comment: Looks like it wasn't vague at all.  Somebody answered in 5 minutes

Comment: although he commented in his answer that there was little information to go on. He got lucky with a guess

Comment: Regardless, I'm glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like browser caching. Clear your browser history or try the application from different web browser.

Comment: I agree there is little information about what is the issue here

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!